# How to scale such system?

Tags: architecture, dns, scalability, load-balancing

Currently I have a single instance of an application deployed in Europe. It exposes some functionality through Web Services (SOAP). There are many clients (a few thousands) that are using it worldwide (mainly North America, Europe and Asia). In the current setup some of the clients must make WS call to an application deployed on a different continent which significantly increases the response time. About the calls character - the payload is small but the calls are made often.

Now my idea is to simply deploy more instances of the application so that there is one in each geo region. But then there is a problem of how to load balance / load distribute requests over different instances.

Approach #1.

I was thinking at the beginning about some HTTP level load balancing - to have one host that exposes the same WS methods and just delegates them to a different application instances. But I think in this solution I wouldn't gain anything in terms of transmission time - the whole request would have to go to one central location, then to the destination. So the packets route would be even longer than with a single instance.

Approach #2.

Then I thought about load balancing on the DNS level. The DNS lookup must be done anyway and if the returned IP could point to the closes geo located instance that would be it! But this solution seems to be way more complex because I would have to deploy a new DNS system (or just configure the one that my company uses if it supports something like this). Also a quick search on google showed mostly commercial DNS based load balancers.

Questions I would like some help answering are:

1) Did I miss anything in any of the above 2 approaches?

2) Is there any better approach for this problem and what that could be exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Let's keep two concepts seperate:

1) Load Balancing

As the name implies, this distributes the load between multiple servers. While this does not generally affect transmission times, it will if the servers are in different geographical regions. But not in in a good way -- say you place server 1 in region A, and server 2 in region B, then load balance between the two, clients of either region will occasionally end up taking roundtrips to the farest region. E.g. a round-robin load balancing will distribute half of all calls to region A, the other half to region B, independent of the client's region.

Both of your approaches are effectively load balancing scenarios -- whether you do this at the level of the DNS or the web server does not matter that much.

2) Geographical Locality

In this approach, which you hint at in your approach #2, servers are placed as close as possible to their clients. What you need in this case is some form of *routing*. In other words, either your DNS needs to figure out which client is in which region, and return the respective server address, or your web server needs to tell a client to talk to a different server.

Based on your scenario I presume you want 2). There are several ways to achieve this:

a) use a Geo-DNS provider (search for geo dns), whereby the DNS server reroutes to the closest server

b) if Geo-DNS is not an option, you could have the clients check back to your main web server for every first request or at least periodically (e.g. once a day, once an hour). Then, have the web server figure out the client's region and ask it to redirect to the closest server.

c) use a "geo-aware" front-end reverse proxy such as nginx, as described in this [example](http://dodizzle.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/route-requests-by-country-code-using-nginx-an/)